# Steam Shower Requirements

Tags: electrical, gfci

I am installing a steam shower in Ontario, Canada. The unit is "**TMG Industrial SR-915**". The electrical specifications are listed as **220v/2.8 KW with gfci**.

My questions:

- The cord coming from the steam generator includes a test/reset button component. Is this gfci ?
- Or does the breaker need to be gfci also?
- Can I install a plug and receptacle under the tub portion (next to where the steam generator is positioned)?

Comment: This item is CSA-listed, yes?  As part of approving the appliance, CSA also approves the instructions, and Code requires you install according to instructions. So while it's common to throw away the instructions, with electrical you do have to read them.

Comment: No electrical instructions were included.

Comment: Where did you get this thing from?

Comment: TPE first thing I did was google it... a quickie look tells me the product and maker seems *very Canadian* with a bricks-n-mortar presence in BC CA.  That was a quickie, I didn't do the full research like with that company whose USA HQ turned out to be a Sunnyvale apartment, remember them? lol. Anyway giving benefit of the doubt, I presume it's CSA listed, implying there will be labeling and instructions.  Maybe they're on the Web.

Comment: Be aware that there is issues with the Steamer valve electronics! My unit started smoking after a few months and quit and TMI Industries will not warranty this unless bought directly through them! If you do some searching you will see this is an issue many have experienced.